# Write URL to custom route in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, razor, parameters, html.actionlink

I have declared custom routes similar to this: [ASP.MVC routes without Details action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411013/asp-mvc-routes-without-details-action)

Here is my route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Profile",
    url: "Profile/{aScreenName}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Profile", action = "Index", aScreenName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I thought this looked neater, but now I am struggling to find a way to create a hyperlink to these routes in Razor. The problem is everything I try wants an object and automatically tries to treat it as a full query string. I can't find the right helper to do this. I have tried `@html`, `@url`, and `@href`.

Does anybody know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Profile", new { aScreenName = "yourScreenName" })">click here</a>
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("click here", "Index", "Profile", new { aScreenName = "yourScreenName" })
```

Comment: thanks. i was so close i tried <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Profile", new {  "yourScreenName" }) cheers paul